# Sequelize internal error server in request

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I followed the official documentation of sequelize and sequelize cli, using sequelize cli I was successful and managed to perform my migrations to the database, but now when creating user and testing in postman, I can only get internal error server 500 without being able to succeed in the request.

CustomerController

```
const Customer = require('../../models/customer');

module.exports = {
    async store (req, res) {
        try {
            const { name, email, password, country, city, state, address, postalCode } = req.body;

            const createdCustomer = await Customer.create({ name, email, password, country, city, state, address, postalCode })
            
            return res.status(200).json(createdCustomer);
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }
    }

}
```

route

```
const router = require('express').Router();

const CreateCustomer = require('../controllers/CustomerController/CreateCustomer');

router.post('/', CreateCustomer.store);

module.exports = router;
```

databaseConfig

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('purchasedata', process.env.NAME, proccess.env.PASSWORD, {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres', 
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

customer Model

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Customer extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  Customer.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    country: DataTypes.STRING,
    city: DataTypes.STRING,
    state: DataTypes.STRING,
    address: DataTypes.STRING,
    postalCode: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Customer',
  });
  return Customer;
};
```

app.js

```
const app = require('./app');

const sequelize  = require('./database/config');

async function connection() {
    const port = process.env.PORT;
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
        app.listen(port);
        console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

connection();
```

server.js

```
const app = require('./app');

const sequelize  = require('./database/config');

async function connection() {
    const port = process.env.PORT;
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
        app.listen(port);
        console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

connection();
```

But my console returns that the database has been successfully connected, and when the request fails at status 500 I don't get any error in the console. Thanks

Comment: You don't get any error on console because you're catching it and sending back a 500 response. You need to log it there.

Comment: "Customer.create is not a function"

Comment: That's because your Customer model file is returning a function, not a model.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Think about why your Customer model file is exporting a function and not the model itself. What are the `sequelize` and `DataTypes` arguments for that function? Could you get what those arguments represent in another way, perhaps by using `require('./databaseConfig')`?

Comment: Perhaps the ideal would be to import the way { Customer } = require('../../models/customer');?